# Choosing the right storage in C (X,Y,state)

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, storage, allocation

I'm just starting to write a new project which should read in X and Y coordinates (which can go from 0 to 4,000,000,000) and store those points.

Because I don't know how many points I'll have to store, I have to allocate the memory needed while the program is running.

Then I'd like to find neighboring points (horizontal&vertical) to  create "islands" and store all connected points in a group.

Now I'm not quite sure which datatype or how to store the coordinates at all.
My very first idea was to have like a 2d array[x][y] which stores the state of that exact point. So if I'm on position array[5][5] i could easily request the state of the next point by adding x+1 (array[6][5]). 
Problem with that is I would have to initialize an array which also holds points, that are not occupied at all and I think array[4,000,000,000][4,000,000,000] wouldn't work anywas.

So what would be the best storage so I'm able to read a points state which allows me to find the neighbouring points?

thanks in advance,
D

**Edit:** Also each island can have gaps

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: @user3386109 What keeps you from turning that (excellent, thanks) link into an answer? I would love this to be among the few code-free but on-topic (in my opinion and there are no close-votes yet), well-asked and well-answered questions.

Comment: The k-d tree implementation may well be a bit beyond our questioner here. As an alternative, there is no need to define storage for the entire 4Bx4B grid to define points within that range. Rather than think array of `[x][y]`, why not simply define a `struct point { uint32_t x, y };` Then you would simply need to create an array of struct for the points you have and dynamically allocate storage. You could then just compute your neighbor info based upon the location of each point. (you can also add whatever `state` info you need as well)

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps a hash table?

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for that, I'll have to read in to see if this is the right use for my problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin a strukt of uints with an int state might work, but for the worst case, where there is only one "island" from X:0 to 4B and Y: 0 to 4B, wouldn't that blow up my strukt array again?

Comment: You can easily declare your `struct point { uint32_t x, y; int state };` (or just add state as another `uint32_t`, e.g. `struct point { uint32_t x, y, state; };`). As for the island, it doesn't matter whether you have 4-points defining the island or 400. You only need to store the data for the points you use. If it happens to be from `x=2 to x=10` and `y=50000 to y=50008` (or 3 billion later for each) you simply have the same number of points to store and your reference of where it is located in space is provided by the `x,y` values themselves. Start simple than add to your model.

Comment: I just couldn't think of an easy way to go through all points to check if its connected to any other point (also there can be gaps in an island). I do get your idea of the strukt, but I'm not yet convinced it would work well for my case. Later I want to backtrack through all islands, to see if they hold specific forms (e.g. 4x4 blocks).. although how would you check the state for example position ( x+1,y )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a data structure requires a lot of information about what the program is to do and how it'll be used. You have given us some information but more information will be needed to find the best data structure.

With the information given my first idea is a linked list of linked lists. The "outer" linked list could represent rows that are present (sorted) and the "inner" linked lists would represent the columns that are present (sorted) for that row.

Something like:

```
struct column
{
    uint32_t cidx;
    struct column* next;
}

struct row
{
    uint32_t ridx;
    struct column* column;
    struct row* next;
}
```

The benefit of linked lists is that it's easy to insert elements in sorted order. Having the points in sorted order will help you look for "islands". For instance if you are looking at row 18, column 1000 and want to check if row 19, column 1000 exists you first check if the `next` row-element is for row 19 and - if it is - you go through the corresponding column linked list to see if 1000 is present.

Comment: Well when all Island are stored, I want to go through all islands to see if i could fill them completely with forms (e.g. 4x4 blocks).

Comment: @DavidDabrue Should be doable with the described data structure

Answer (score 1):

Using a 2D array indexed by the coordinates is impractical because of the range of these coordinates: `0..4000000000`. That is 16 billion billion cells, not only does it exceed current conceivable RAM space, but scanning such a vast almost empty area is going to be very inefficient too.

You should look into [Quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or similar data structures fit for storing geographical data.

Comment: thanks, I'm not quite sure if I can handle the pointers when building the quadtree, but im reading my way in to it right now